# Sort 10 integer numbers read from keyboard and display in ascending order

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86-16, bubble-sort

I managed to write this code for turbo debugger in assembly language which is meant to sort 10 integer numbers read from the keyboard and display them in ascending order but it keeps looping B to infinite..
The code is :

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
strg1 DB 'Insert numbers: $'
strg2 DB 'Sorted numbers: $'
Arr Db 10 dup(?)
v dw ?
.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ah,9
lea dx,strg1
int 21h

mov dl,0ah
mov ah,2
int 21h

;inputs
mov di,0
mov cx,10
Input_loop:

mov ah,1
int 21h
mov arr[di],al

mov dl,0ah
mov ah,2
int 21h
inc di
loop Input_loop

mov v,0
sort:

mov di,0
mov cx,10
sub cx,v

B:
mov al,Arr[di]
cmp al,Arr[di+1]
jng C

mov al,Arr[di]
xchg al,Arr[di+1]
mov Arr[di],al
c:
inc di
loop B
inc v
cmp v,10
jne sort

;Output
mov ah,9
lea dx,strg2
int 21h

mov dl,0ah
mov ah,2
int 21h

mov di,0
mov cx,10
Output_loop:

mov dl,Arr[di]
mov ah,2
int 21h
inc di

mov dl,0ah
mov ah,2
int 21h
loop output_loop

mov ah,4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

It is running perfectly, I can enter my desired numbers to be sorted, and then when it reaches c: , it just keeps looping B to infinite and it really makes me mad . Do you have any idea what went wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: What's in the register at that point?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: https://ibb.co/Dpx7X9G this is what it looked when it first got to  "loop B" sequence. And then after a lot of F7`s on DosBox. The di has changed from 0001 to 000A-B-C etc, to 0010 or 00AB .

Comment: To be honest I am at the beggining and at school we've only been taught how to run these .asm files on DosBox .

Comment: [understanding-the-dosbox-debug-screen](https://zwomp.com/index.php/2020/05/01/understanding-the-dosbox-debug-screen/)

Comment: Programming requires debugging skills; assembly is no different.  Learn the debugger and how to single step debug and verify (1) computed values (2) control flow.

Comment: hi, i cant install the debugger on my pc.

Comment: Ok, you should figure that out because debugging by posting to an internet Q&A website is going to be very painful in the long run.

Comment: Hi George, I think programming (at this scale) should be done on paper too, so a debugger makes it a lot easier, but is not required. If you don't have one, you can always test smaller steps. Take a smaller step of your code and test that step. Copy that step and look what goes in and what comes out. If that works, try to test the next step. At the end you'll probably get the step that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Arr Db 10 dup(?)
> v dw ?
> ```

In an array that has **10** elements, you can do **9** pairwise comparisons at most.
Your code does 10 comparisons and will move whatever byte is stored after the array, and that is probably a zero, down in memory!

Initialize *v* at 1:

```
mov v, 1
sort:
```

**This is the only modification that I made and your program ran perfectly in DOSBox. I assembled the source using TASM 4.1 followed by TLINK**

---

### A better BubbleSort

0. Don't use BubbleSort, better algorithms exist! :-)
   =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
1. Better use a register like `SI` instead of a memory based variable *v*.
2. Use downcounting for the outer loop count.
3. Because your elements are byte-sized, you can read and write two elements together.
4. Keep addressing modes simplest/shortest (using `[di]` instead of `Arr[di]`).
5. Avoid the slow `LOOP` instruction.
6. Use meaningful names for your labels.
7. Avoid using `XCHG` between a register and memory.
8. Use unsigned conditional jumps after comparing unsigned quantities like characters "0" to "9" (using `jna` instead of `jng`).

```
  mov  si, 10-1
Outer:
  mov  di, offset Arr
  mov  cx, si
Inner:
  mov  ax, [di]
  cmp  al, ah
  jna  Skip
  xchg al, ah
  mov  [di], ax
Skip:
  inc  di
  dec  cx
  jnz  Inner

  dec  si
  jnz  Outer
```