# How does this 8086 code of ascending-sort work?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bubble-sort, emu8086

I am currently learning 8086 programming and this one was demonstrated in our lab on a 8086 kit. The following code sorts sequence of numbers to ascending order:

```
mov si, 2000
mov cl, [si]
dec cl
loop1: mov si, 2000
       mov ch, [si]
       dec ch
       inc si
       loop2: mov al, [si]
              inc si
              cmp al, [si]
              
              jc loop3

              xchg al, [si]
              dec si
              xchg di, [si]
              inc si

       loop3: dec ch
              jnz loop2
       dec cl
       jnz loop1
int a5
```

How exactly does this function?

Say we have an array of N numbers d1, d2, ..., dN as follows:

```
Address |2000|2001|2002|2003|...|2000+N|...|
Data    |N   |d1  |d2  |d3  |...|dN    |...|
        |si  |

cl <-- [si]
{cl:N --> N-1}
```

LOOP 1:

```
ch <-- [si]
{ch:N --> N-1}
si --> si+1
Address |2000|2001|2002|2003|...|2000+N|...|
Data    |N   |d1  |d2  |d3  |...|dN    |...|
             |si  |
```

LOOP 2:

```
al <-- [si] = d1
si --> si+1
Address |2000|2001|2002|2003|...|2000+N|...|
Data    |N   |d1  |d2  |d3  |...|dN    |...|
                  |si  |
Compare [si] = d2 with al = d1.
If d1 > d2, jump to LOOP 3,
else d1 <= d2 and exchange d1 in al with d2 at si = 2002.
al = d2
Address |2000|2001|2002|2003|...|2000+N|...|
Data    |N   |d1  |d1  |d3  |...|dN    |...|
                  |si  |
si --> si - 1
[di] = d1 (at 2001)
```

LOOP 3:

```
{ch:N-1 --> N-2}
If ch is not zero then jump to LOOP 2.
al <-- [si] = d2 and so on.
```

At this point I feel like I am losing track of how the code really works. So, how does this work? Am I missing something? The example demonstrated was:

```
Address |2000|2001|2002|2003|2004|2005|...|
Input   |5   |04  |03  |01  |00  |02  |...|
Output  |5   |00  |01  |02  |03  |04  |...|
```

Comment: That pair of `xchg` ops on adjacent elements looks almost like the `swap` in a Bubble Sort.  But the second swap is with 16-bit `di`, not 8-bit `al`, so that's super weird.  Also, IDK why they didn't `xchg di, [si-1]`.  According to https://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~fpf/Uebungen/GdR-SS02/opcode_i.html, `[si+disp]` might be at worst 6 cycles slower than `[si]`, same as `dec`+`inc`, but only costs 1 extra byte of code size and memory access including code-fetch is the normal bottleneck on 8086, especially with lots of data memory access like here.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through it and watching memory contents change?  (And seeing what ends up in `di`?)  I think this would be a normal (but slow because of `xchg`) bubble sort if both `xchg` instructions were with `al`.

Comment: Your diagram for LOOP 2 shows `[di] = d1 (at 2001)`.  But that's not accurate, it's a 16-bit register so it has 2 copies of `d1`.  I think it's always going to end up loading 2 of the same value, but the store might be from a much older value if there haven't been any swaps recently.

Comment: @PeterCordes, man I am just a beginner in this subject and even I find the above code "not so starightforward" to understand. Plus our exams are near, I would be so grateful if you could post a better-version of this code that is easy to understand.

Comment: I just tried this code (with ESI instead of SI, and `arr` instead of `2000` so I could use NASM in 32-bit mode).  It doesn't work.  Starting with `arr: db 5, 3, 7, 2, 4, 1` and `di`=0000 (the code uses the incoming value of DI!), it leaves memory holding `{0x5, 0x7, 0x7, 0x7, 0x7, 0x7}`, i.e. in this case it happened to broadcast the highest element.  Perhaps `di` is a typo for `al`?  The shapes of the letters are somewhat similar, perhaps an OCR error?  If the `xchg di` was `xchg al`, it would be a normal bubble-sort.  `jc` is a synonym for `jb` (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc).

Comment: After changing `xchg di` to `xchg al`, the two `xchg` instructions are just an inefficient swap since `al` holds the lower-address value to start with.  The second one should just be `mov [si - 1], al` since the top of the loop reloads `al` anyway.  The two halves of CX are a loop counter.  Single-step through it in a debugger.  Or look at other well-commented bubble sort examples, like [Sort 10 integer numbers read from keyboard and display in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65751698) or [Assembly bubble sort swap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11497966)

Comment: See also [Bubble Sort: An Archaeological Algorithmic Analysis](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Eola/papers/bubble.pdf) and [Why bubble sort is not efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61997897) for more about understanding how Bubble Sort is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The troubles in this ascending bubble sort

- There's definitely a typo in `xchg di, [si]`. It should be clear that the code does not use the `di` register anywhere else, so this particular exchange instruction is useless. What would make sense is `xchg al, [si]`, but even better would be a simple `mov [si], al`.
- Apart from bubble sort being the worst sorting method, here they made it extra bad by not acknowledging the most prominent feature of bubble sort which is 'make the max element bubble to the top of the array'. Once the max element has reached the top position, the code should no longer consider that top position and the next iteration should already stop one position earlier.

> At this point I feel like I am losing track of how the code really works. So, how does this work? Am I missing something?

You are mis-interpreting the conditional jump in:

> ```
> cmp al, [si]      <<<< AL = d1, [si], d2
> jc loop3
> ```

when you state:

> ```
> If d1 > d2, jump to LOOP 3,
> else d1 <= d2 and exchange d1 in al with d2 at si = 2002.
> ```

The `jc` instruction should have been written as `jb` that has exactly the same encoding but that better conveys what it does: "If AL is below the byte at [si] then jump to *LOOP3*". So if `d1 < d2` which is just the opposite of what you stated ("if d1 > d2").
Incidently, *LOOP3* is a really bad name for this label! A more suitable name could be *SKIP*.

> I would be so grateful if you could post a better-version of this code that is easy to understand.

```
       mov  si, 2000  ; Where the count resides
       mov  cl, [si]  ; CL is number of elements
       dec  cl        ; CL is number of iterations outer loop
Outer: mov  si, 2001  ; Where the first element resides
       mov  ch, cl    ; Ever smaller number of iterations inner loop (*)
Inner: mov  al, [si]
       inc  si
       cmp  al, [si]  ; Compare two adjacent elements
       jb   Skip      ; Skip the Swap if ordered fine already
Swap:  xchg al, [si]
       mov  [si-1], al
Skip:  dec  ch
       jnz  Inner     ; Iterate on the Inner loop
       dec  cl
       jnz  Outer     ; Iterate on the Outer loop
```

(*) This is the magic that makes bubble sort somewhat acceptable as a sorting method for small arrays!

More about writing a bubble sort code can be found at [Sort 10 integer numbers read from keyboard and display in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65751698).

Comment: *(\*) This is the magic that makes bubble sort somewhat acceptable as a sorting method for small arrays!* - is that supposed to be a footnote for the second bullet point at the top, about the fact that the inner-loop range should shrink?  That's not sufficient; SelectionSort already does that.  And InsertionSort already does that in reverse, with the number of elements the inner loop might scan over growing from 1.  So that just brings Bubble Sort on par in terms of loop ranges, but still significantly worse overall (especially if done with an atomic-RMW-on-386-and-later `xchg`)

Comment: Also, without an early-out for the no-swaps case, Bubble Sort is far worse than Insertion Sort for almost-sorted or already-sorted arrays.  (And even with that, if the one element that needs to move is a "turtle", in the opposite direction from the inner loop, it's not great.  Although Insertion Sort is not great either if the only mis-ordered element is near the start of the array but it needs to be near the end.  It'll copy the intervening elements `m` times, where m is the distance.)  Insertion Sort's early-out behaviour happens for free as the inner loop does 0 iterations.

Comment: You're right that the inner loop range optimization makes Bubble Sort less far behind, so if you have very low standards then I guess it could be acceptable.